# DotNetNuke Module keeps converting itself into Application in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

Bit of a weird one. For some reason one of my DNN modules keeps being converted into an Application in IIS7 in my development environment. Meaning when I try to view a page that contains that module it can't find the module correctly. It's ok if I go into IIS and delete the application, then restart the site but is a bit of a pain and am little worried it might do this when uploaded to the live server and disable the whole site.

Anyone encountered anything like this before? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem with my VS templates, though not for everyone, and it doesn't happen all the time. It stems from Visual Studio, so it shouldn't ever be a problem on your production servers, unless you upload source and try to compile there, than it might be an issue.

Comment: Chris, have you managed to find any tactics to help reduce the chances of DesktopModules folder from converting to a virtual directory?

Comment: @blackhawk unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

HuwD,

A good resource might be my [module template installation video](http://www.dotnetnuclear.com/articles/tabid/88/ID/11/MVP-Module-Development-Template-Installation-Configuration-Troubleshooting.aspx) which gives good information on setting up your development environment and debugging issues (regardless of the template you use).  Check out between 1:30 and 5:00 minutes for the environment setup, and after 19 minutes some of the troubleshooting.

A couple common problems I see Visual Studio doing is creating an unwanted virtual directory on the DesktopModules folder and/or creating an unwanted web.config in the module's root.

Another good resource is [Dnnhero.com](http://dnnhero.com).  In the development section there is a series on DNN7 environment and template setup.

Comment: have you managed to find any tactics to help reduce the chances of DesktopModules folder from converting to a virtual directory?

Answer (score -1):

You may want to give a try a free module called [Users Importer](http://usersimporter.codeplex.com/)  - A bit old but worth a try.

Here is a paid alternative: [Bulk User Manager](http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/bulk-user-manager-v33?r=73311e2a326b411fbbb4)